# Android - Launching an activity from service after force stop / crash

Tags: java, android

I am developing a countdown timer application and want to launch the activity to start after time completes every thing is working fine but after I force stop the app it shows `NullPointerException`. I can't figure out why it is showing this.
here is my java code

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    handler = new Handler();
    x=1;
    //final TimerService timerService=this;
    r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                 if ((minutes >= 0) && (seconds >= 0) && (minutes <= 59) && (seconds <= 59)) {
                 if (seconds == 0 && minutes > 0) {
                     minutes--;
                     seconds = 59;
                 } else if (seconds == 0 && minutes == 0) {
                     try {
                         mins.setEnabled(true);
                         secs.setEnabled(true);
                         Intent ring = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TimerComplete.class);
                         ring.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                         ring.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                         ring.setComponent(new ComponentName(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), TimerComplete.class.getName()));
                         timerService.startActivity(ring);
                         stopSelf();
                         handler.removeCallbacks(this);
                     } catch (Exception e) {
                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     }
                     mins.setText(String.format("%02d", minutes));
                     secs.setText(String.format("%02d", seconds));
                     if (seconds != 0) {
                         seconds--;
                         x++;
                         handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                     }
                } else {
                     mins.setEnabled(true);
                     secs.setEnabled(true);
                     mins.setText("00");
                     secs.setText("00");
                     handler.removeCallbacks(this);
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Time", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
          }
     } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
      }
      };
      handler.post(r);
      return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
  }
```

This function is of static nested class and all the views I am using are of outer class

Comment: Please Read the basics of Android first, you're trying to access the views from service !!! and also need to attach the handler with life cycle methods, so you should learn the basic first -  https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

Comment: paste your error log here

Comment: @noman404 this function is of static nested service class and all he views I am using are of outer class

Comment: provide a proper log then, to get help quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> you can use the timer and set the delay of 1 sec

```
    int myTimeCounter = 60;
    Timer myTimer = new Timer();
    private void startRepeatedTask() {
        myTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        if (myTimeCounter == 0) {
                            myTimer.cancel();
                            callActivity();
                            return;
                        }
                        //Log.d(TAG, "timer=" + String.valueOf(myTimeCounter));
                        myTimeCounter--;
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 0, 1000);
    }
```